# Python/Javascript - Self Updating Webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am hoping that I can be pointed in the right direction as I am completely unsure of how to approach the task I have at hand. I have created a python program that is able to execute some tests and gather information pertinent to the test. My task at hand is to make it so that the information I get is put on a webpage.

The way I am handling the directory is as follows

```
Project
|
+--index.html
+--testcases
   |
   +--testline1
      |
      +--build1
         |
         +--date1
            |
            +--relevantdata.txt
            +--index.html
         +--date2
      +--build2
   +--testline2
   +--testline3
```

Every time I complete a testcase I update the appropriate testline + build by creating a directory with the date and putting relevant information in that directory. Every test case I run creates it's own html page that I would like to be accessible to the user.

Is there a way for me to update the outermost index.html automatically to reflect these changes? I am imagining that the html page will have a sidebar that lets the user pick testline + build + date. Is there a way to update this menu when test cases are completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so let me understand this correctly:

you have `script.py` that does some magic, and creates `testline N` directory + associated files. you then want `Project/index.html` to list all N testlines.

is that correct?

if so, the SIMPLEST way to achieve this is to code the html in a python string, and then programmatically add the new testline link to that string, and then finally write that string to a `index.html` file.

another way to do this is to create a javascript (jquery) in a "mylinks.js" file and have that `mylinks.js` loaded in `index.html`

`<script src="mylinks.js" type="text/javascript">`

your my links would look something like this:

```
$window.onload(function() {
 var $input = $('<input type="button" value="TESTLINE  - N" />');
    $input.appendTo($("body"));
});
```

now all you need to do is programatically (in python), write the for loop in `mylinks.js`

```
string = ''
for [python get number of dirs matching testlineN]:
  string += '$window.onload(function() {
     var $input = $('<input type="button" value="TESTLINE  - N" />');
        $input.appendTo($("body"));
    });'
```

python write to file

some what pseudo code ish, but you should get the gist of it,

Comment: Understood! Was worried that I would need to do the somewhat "janky" use python to write directly to the HTML but I am afraid it can't be helped. Thanks!

Comment: you could write it to a json file, and let javascript read the json object and create the folders for you.